# How to add all links from scrapy in a list?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I made a web spider that scrapes all links in a website using Scrapy. I would like to be able to add all links scraped to a list. However, for every link scraped, it creates its own list. This is my code:

```py
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import sys

process = CrawlerProcess()

class Crawler(CrawlSpider):

    name = "LinkCrawler"
    start_urls = ['https://books.toscrape.com/']
    allowed_domains = ['books.toscrape.com']
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor('/catalogue/'), callback='parse_links', follow=True)]

    def parse_links(self, response):
        list = []
        href = response.xpath('//a/@href').getall()
        for link in href:
            list.append(link)
        print(list)
        print('')


    def file():
    original_stdout = sys.stdout
    with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
        sys.stdout = f
        process.crawl(Crawler)
        process.start()
        sys.stdout = original_stdout
        f.close()


    file()
```

This is a sample outcome:

```
['../../../index.html', '../../../index.html', 'index.html', '../books/travel_2/index.html', '../books/mystery_3/index.html']

['../../../1000-places-to-see-before-you-die_1/index.html', '../../../1000-places-to-see-before-you-die_1/index.html']

['../../../old-records-never-die-one-mans-quest-for-his-vinyl-and-his-past_39/index.html', '../../../forever-rockers-the-rocker-12_19/index.html', '../../../forever-rockers-the-rocker-12_19/index.html']
```

However, I would like it to be:

```
['../../../index.html', '../../../index.html', 'index.html', '../books/travel_2/index.html', '../books/mystery_3/index.html', '../../../1000-places-to-see-before-you-die_1/index.html', '../../../1000-places-to-see-before-you-die_1/index.html', '../../../old-records-never-die-one-mans-quest-for-his-vinyl-and-his-past_39/index.html', '../../../forever-rockers-the-rocker-12_19/index.html', '../../../forever-rockers-the-rocker-12_19/index.html']
```

Comment: can i ask why u used this complex method with stdout to output like a lisk to a file, instead of the scrapy built in which outputs to csv, json and others?

Comment: @jimakr I just wanted to output it to a text file in this format

Comment: @PyProgrammer Why use that format, specifically?

Comment: @AMC, I used that format for specific testing purposes.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, can you elaborate?

Comment: @AMC, Don't worry about it, I already found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I found that you can simply create a global variable and print it.

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
process = CrawlerProcess()

list = []

class Crawler(CrawlSpider):

   name = "LinkCrawler"
   start_urls = ['https://books.toscrape.com/']
   allowed_domains = ['books.toscrape.com']
   rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor('/catalogue/'), callback='parse_links', follow=True)]

   def parse_links(self, response):
      href = response.xpath('//a/@href').getall()
      for link in href:
         list.append(link)

print(list)
```